# How to escape single quote within another string which contains single quote in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I want to escape single quote within another string.

I have the following string:

```
'I'm a javascript programmer'
```

In the above string , I need to escape single quote

and the expected output is:

```
'I\'m a javascript programmer'
```

I required this to handle in eval() in javascript.

The String would be like this...

```
"[['string's one','string two','string's three']]"
```

How to solve this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Best approach: Find a solution that doesn't involve using `eval`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, as you have the answer in your question. `'` can be escaped in javascript by either denoting the string with `""` or by escaping the quotes as in your `'I\'m a javascript programmer'`

Comment: Can you show a more complete sample of what you are doing? you already have 3 answers showing you what you already know, more than likely the problem is with how you are applying this knowledge.

Comment: I think this is the complete one. I need to escape single quote within single quoted string.

Comment: Right, which VajNyiaj's answer correctly does but you claim it doesn't work.

Comment: So you want to escape quotes in the middle of the string, but not in the beginning and the end?

Comment: Thanks for others who helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can do the trick:

```
var str = "'I'm a js programer.'";
str.replace(/(\w)'(\w)/g, "$1\\\'$2");
```

Comment: Oops. It adds slash at first position only. How to remove that?

Comment: Sorry shimon. It still adds slash at the end of string,but removes at first position.

Comment: Strange, because it works for me.. Can you post the exact test string?

Comment: Sorry shimon. I have not noticed that you have change the regex with 'w'.

Comment: Wow. It is worked fine. Simply superb. You helped me lot. thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. Try a string with two quotes next to each other, e.g. `"'I''m a js programer.'"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "my string's"
s = s.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

Comment: Sorry I tried this previously. Not working. It adds slash at the begin and end of string also.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to escape quotes in an html string would be with a character entity.

```
'I&apos;m a javascript programmer'
```

The same goes for double quotes:

```
'&quot;I&apos;m a javascript programmer&quot;'
```

Comment: But the string comes from server. how to handle this.

Comment: The server can escape it for you. Coldfusion/Railo for example has an `HTMLEditFormat` method that automatically makes these conversions for you.

Comment: But I get it from mysql query itself with group concat method.

Comment: mysql has a replace method, so i guess that's an option

Answer (score 0):

You can try [lookahead assertions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to achieve the desired effect:

```
var str = "'I'm a javascript's programmer'";
str = str.replace(/(?!^)'(?!$)/g, "\\'");
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ng4rX/5/)). Unlike Shimon's answer, this can also deal with double single quotes (`''`).

Negative lookahead assertion `(?! )`doesn't do any matching by itself but it ensures that the asserted expression doesn't occur at the given position (i.e. start of string `^` doesn't occur before the quote and end of string `$` doesn't occur after the quote).

Comment: It is working nice in browser. But is there any regex available to handle this?